# Get the timestamp for product visibility change only

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, product

In WooCommerce, I would like to get the date (**`timestamp`**), when Admin has changed a product's visibility (visible - hidden).

Any ideas how to make this?

I tried the **last edit timestamp**, but I would like to have a **`timestamp`** only this particular change.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> There is no specific **timestamp** for only visibility changed value. If you change something else in the product the last edit timestamp will also be changed.

There is a solution hooking a custom a function in **`'save_post'`** WordPress backend hook, where you will test **`$_REQUEST['visibility']`** (or alternatively **`$_POST['visibility']`**.

**If a new value is set for the product visibility**, we create / update a custom **post_meta** **`key`** **`'visibility_timestamp'`** with the modification timestamp **`value`**.

Here is that code:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'custom_datestamp_for_product_visibility', 1, 1 );
function custom_datestamp_for_product_visibility( $post_id ){

    // Get the post object
    $post = get_post( $post_id );

    if( $post->post_type == 'product' ) {
        $visibility = $_REQUEST['visibility'];
        if(!empty($visibility))
        {
            // Current timestamp (now)
            $now = date('y-m-d H:i:s'); 

            // Creating (or updating) your visibility change timestamp 
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'visibility_change', $today );
        }
    }
}
```

**This code is tested and is fully functional.**

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*

> **Usage in your code** (Getting the visibility timestamp value with the product ID):
>
> ```
> $visibility_timestamp_change = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_visibility_change', true);
> ```
>
> You can also access this custom field value within the Admin product edit mode view in the **Custom Fields Metabox**, where you will see the value for **`visibility_change`** custom field.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but something isn't working right. I made a custom text field. Also in your code you have to change update_post_meta with $now variable. It seems to work but only in first time. If i change again the visibility nothing happens. Also if first time i just update the product the custom field gets the timestamp.

Comment: @GeorgeNtoum I am going to find a working turn around… let me some time to find it. I will tell you when I will update may answer.

Comment: Thanks you. If you find something please post it. I' m also trying to resolve it. If i will figure something out i'll let you know